# REST Call using 'requests' library in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, rest, curl, python-requests

I am trying to execute a REST POST call using 'request' library, and i am using python 2.7

What happening is, somehow the call is not getting executed via python script and and i am getting HTTPS connection error saying cannot connect to proxy.

I have verified in my system, proxy settings has no issue. In the *same setup* i am able to execute the *same REST* call using **POSTMAN client *&* cURL**.

Below is code snippet: (here the 'hostname' is private IP address and accessible internally only)

```
import requests
import json
import pprint
import sys

url = "https://<hostname>/rest/login-sessions"
json_data = {'authLoginDomain':'',
             'password':'abc',
             'userName':'xyz',
             'loginMsgAck':'true'}
reqHeaders = {'Content-type':'application/json',
              'X-Api-Version':'200'}
try:
    reqPost = requests.post(url,data=json_data,headers=reqHeaders,verify = False)
    pprint.pprint(resPost.json())
except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
    print "Re-Try Again"
except requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects:
    print "Try with a different URL"
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print e 
    sys.exit(1)
```

Error code pasted below:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='<hostIP>', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /rest/login-sessions (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel connection failed: 503 Service Unavailable',)))
```

I tried finding solutions available in the web but none of them are working for me. I am confuse because when i am trying to execute the REST call via a python script then only it happening, via cURL & Postman i am able to do the same.

Please suggest if i am doing some mistake here OR any better way available to this.

I want to do it with python 'requests' library only. Also, i tried executing it with cURL using python subprocess, there also i am getting the same error.

Comment: It appears you are using a proxy and that it is misconfigured for requests. Without further information, there's not much we can do to help. I can take a guess that your `https_proxy` environment variable is set to something like `https://proxy_ip:proxy_port/` and it should be `http://proxy_ip:proxy_port/` instead but I can't be certain without more information.

Comment: @sigmavirus24: yes, earlier the proxy was like that. now i have removed all proxy. without proxy it works fine with curl & postman. I tried pinging the host IP with a small python script and its returning TRUE. i am expecting there is no issue with the python env settings as well.

Comment: Merely pinging an IP with a python script does not mean that requests has stopped detecting your proxies and has stopped trying to use them.